# How to set close button X to Bootstrap gallery lightbox?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal, lightbox

I have a bootstrap image gallery with lightbox and I'd like to show the close button X on the modal lightbox. This is my HTML:

```
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <a href="https://farm1.staticflickr.com/665/23578574946_b6f90e1ca8_k.jpg" data-toggle="lightbox">
                <img src="https://farm1.staticflickr.com/665/23578574946_b6f90e1ca8_k.jpg" class="img-fluid">
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And this is my JS:

```
$(document).on('click', '[data-toggle="lightbox"]', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).ekkoLightbox();
    })
```

I know, I should set 'alwaysShowClose' to 'true' but I don't understand where.

Comment: Here it's where I took the modal plugin http://ashleydw.github.io/lightbox/

Answer (score 2):

The close button for a modal in Bootstrap 4 is this:

```
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
</button>
```

The `&times;` thingy is the X.

But in order for that button to work, you must use proper modal components.

Here's a working example:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<div class="container m-1">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
            <button type="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <img src="https://farm1.staticflickr.com/665/23578574946_b6f90e1ca8_k.jpg" class="img-fluid">
                </div>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <img class="img-fluid" src="https://farm1.staticflickr.com/665/23578574946_b6f90e1ca8_k.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Reference:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! In the end I realised that it would have been easier to use the basic bootstrap modal from the beginning.

Comment: Yes, you can get the same result with less headache. :D

Answer (score 2):

You pass the paramenter on the function call

```
$(document).on('click', '[data-toggle="lightbox"]', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).ekkoLightbox({
            alwaysShowClose: true
        });
    })
```